# Ensuring that user has workbook open for editing when they start editing things

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook on the work intranet SharePoint server, and I want to alert users the first time they edit something if they aren't the person who has it open for editing.  If they are not, I would like to close the workbook and open it for editing.

```
Public CheckedIfThisUserEditing As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UserInput As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim WorkbookAddress As String
    If Not CheckedIfThisUserEditing = True Then
        CheckedIfThisUserEditing = True
        If Not Application.UserName = ThisWorkbook.WriteReservedBy Then
            UserInput = MsgBox("You don't have this workbook open for editing, open workbook for editing?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1 + vbExclamation, "Not open for editing")
            If UserInput = vbYes Then
                WorkbookAddress = ThisWorkbook.FullName
                Call ThisWorkbook.Close(False)
                Call Workbooks.Open(WorkbookAddress, False, False, , , , , , , True, True)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Right now it closes the workbook, but does not open it back up for editing.  Not sure where to go from here.  I want to ensure they have the freshest copy of it from the server, and aren't editing old data then overwriting other people's changes that occurred while they had it open but not write reserved.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Close` closes the workbook and ends your code execution.

Comment: There are certain things VBA code can't do. Closing the host document and then re-opening it is one of those things. Try running code in the `Workbook.Open` handler to validate whether the file is write-enabled, tell the user about, *and have them do what needs to be done*. Reopening the same workbook will most likely just reopen it in read-only mode again. Note that none of this would be a problem with Office 365 online collab, where everyone can use the file at the same time (but, no VBA code then).

Comment: Maybe I should just change the `MsgBox` and get rid of the `Workbooks.Open`.  Most users are going to want to open it read-only (or at least I want them to) so they can use the reports and such while the few people who enter that data pass it back and forth.  Would that open method not open it for editing if it did execute?

Comment: Looks like that code does not open it for editing.  Any idea what might?  Maybe `Call ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess(xlReadWrite, , True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why `ThisWorkbook.LockServerFile` wants to throw an error if someone else is editing, but I think this will do the trick.

```
Public Sub EditGuard()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not CheckedIfThisUserEditing = True Then
        CheckedIfThisUserEditing = True
        If Not Application.UserName = ThisWorkbook.WriteReservedBy Then
            ThisWorkbook.LockServerFile
            If Not Application.UserName = ThisWorkbook.WriteReservedBy Then Call MsgBox("You don't have this workbook open for editing.", vbOKOnly + vbDefaultButton1 + vbExclamation, "Not open for editing")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```